# How many suggested edits are suggested a day on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, data-explorer

I've been active on the suggested edits queue recently, and I'm wondering just how many suggested edits Stack Overflow gets a day. I'd also like to learn how to use the Data Explorer look these kind of things up myself.

I've tried searching on the data explorer, and https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new is very intimidating as I've never used it before, and it just provides a list of 100s of column names and a textbox. I think I want to count SuggestedEditId where no null in a 24 hour period, but I'm unsure how to write that query. Some support learning and using this to accomplish my particular query would be appreciated.

Comment: So what problem are you having trying to compute the stat?

Comment: Edited the question to hopefully explain my issues using the data-explorer.

Comment: So in other words you gave up without even trying, so you want someone else to just do it for you instead of learning.

Comment: They do have an awesome tutorial: https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grid on the right in SEDE is **tables**, then columns. The table you want is `SuggestedEdits`, which looks like:

[image]

A query like:

```
select cast(CreationDate as date) [Date], COUNT(1)
from SuggestedEdits
where CreationDate >= '01 Jan 2018'
group by cast( CreationDate as date)
order by cast(CreationDate as date) desc
```

would do it, which would be something like: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/782901/suggested-edits-per-day#graph

Comment: This makes sense, I was looking at the wrong tables anyways. I'll try to use this in the future when I write queries.